# Need a twin group by value

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a query something like this,

```
SELECT SOME_ID, COUNT(ANOTHER_ID) AS WITHOUT_FILTER 
from SOME_TABLE GROUP BY SOME_ID
```

this returns me

```
+------------+------------------+
| SOME_ID    | WITHOUT_FILTER   |
+------------+------------------+
|  1         | 40               |
|  2         | 30               |
+------------+------------------+
```

I have the same query with a condition which gives me filtered values.

```
SELECT SOME_ID, COUNT(ANOTHER_ID) AS WITH_FILTER 
from SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_COL > 10 GROUP BY SOME_ID
```

which returns obviously lesser values in the grouped_by section

```
+------------+----------------+
| SOME_ID    | WITH_FILTER    |
+------------+----------------+
|  1         | 20             |
|  2         | 15             |
+------------+----------------+
```

Now, I need a query to give me both the count values ie with condition and without condition in one single query. The result should be like this

```
+----------+----------------+---------------+
| SOME_ID  | WITHOUT_FILTER | WITH_FILTER   |
+----------+----------------+---------------+
|  1       | 40             | 20            |
|  2       | 30             | 15            |
+------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT 
    SOME_ID, 
    COUNT(ANOTHER_ID) AS WITHOUT_FILTER
    SUM(case when SOME_CONDITION then 1 else 0 end) AS WITH_FILTER

from SOME_TABLE GROUP BY SOME_ID
```

Comment: +1 I was beat twice: by the answer and by @JoeStefanelli in the "beat me" comment

Comment: I wrote a complementary answer, exploring the issue a little further.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a "COUNT, but only for the rows meeting a condition" effect by using IF() and SUM.

```
 SELECT SOME_ID, 
        COUNT(ANOTHER_ID) AS WITHOUT_FILTER,
        SUM(IF(SOME_COL > 10, 1, 0)) AS WITH_FILTER
 FROM SOME_TABLE GROUP BY SOME_ID
```

(Note: This solution, and all the others except Adrian's, has a subtle problem if ANOTHER_ID is ever NULL.  If that's the case, then Adrian's is the only one that is truly correct).

Answer (score 1):

For learning purposes, here are my 2 cents. You can use `COUNT` on both fields:

```
SELECT SOME_ID, 
       COUNT(ANOTHER_ID) AS WITHOUT_FILTER
       COUNT(case 
               when WHEN SOME_COL > 10 then ANOTHER_ID 
               else NULL 
             end) AS WITH_FILTER
from SOME_TABLE GROUP BY SOME_ID
```

The trick is that `COUNT` counts non-null values. This feature is ANSI SQL supported, BTW.

Comment: I'm thinking that, using this technique, to be completely consistent between the two resulting COUNT columns you would want to use `then ANOTHER_ID` as the value to count.  Otherwise, you'll COUNT cases where ANOTHER_ID is NULL, but only in the second column and could, conceivably, wind up with a higher WITH_FILTER than WITHOUT_FILTER count.  (All the other solutions, including mine, have the same problem).

Comment: Thinking about it, with that one change, this is actually the only really correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

try CASE and SUM combined:

```
SELECT SOME_ID, COUNT(ANOTHER_ID) as WITHOUT_FILTER,
SUM(CASE WHEN SOME_COL > 10 THEN 1 else 0 END) as WITH_FILTER
from SOME_TABLE GROUP BY SOME_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.SOME_ID, 
       COUNT(T1.ANOTHER_ID) AS WITH_FILTER,
       COUNT(T2.ANOTHER_ID) AS WITHOUT_FILTER 
FROM   SOME_TABLE as T1, 
       SOME_TABLE as T2
WHERE 
      T1.SOME_ID=T2.SOME_ID
  AND T2.SOME_COL > 10
GROUP BY T1.SOME_ID, T2.SOME_ID
```

Or you can do it with 2 views merging if your conditions become too touchy